# PHP redirecting while including a file

Tags: php, apache

I have a website I am working on that I want the profile.php page to use $_SESSION[current_user].  That variable was from a file auth.php which redirects the page after authenticating login from a form.

auth.php has a header('Location: /profile.php'); and this causes a redirect loop when I try to include 'auth.php'; on the profile page.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Don't include it in the profile page script.

Comment: The server sets $_SESSION after the redirect, so manually set it the first time for the page, then set it from the $_SESSION every other time in an if else action.  You can set a variable in the reverse way the same way you do to set it.